# Getting Waring while up the first network using CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have downloaded latest fabric samples and binaries. 
Than I have run the following command:-

> > ./byfn.sh up -c mychannel -s couchdb

**Getting Warning:-**

> > LOCAL_VERSION=1.3.0
> >
> > DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.3.0-rc1
> >
> > ```
> >       WARNING
> > ```
> >
> > Local fabric binaries and docker images are
> >        out of  sync. This may cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue.  Looks like there was a minor issue in how the version is being set in a few of the binaries.

You can double-check this.  Assuming you downloaded things into the fabric-samples directory, you should be able to find the binaries in the `fabric-samples/bin` directory.

So from the `fabric-samples` directory, run

`./bin/peer version`
which should output something starting with

```
Version: 1.3.0-rc1
Commit SHA: 25f79cd
```

Then run `./bin/configtxgen --version`
which should output

```
Version: 1.3.0
Commit SHA: 25f79cd
```

As long as the **Commit SHA** values are the same, you are fine